# In pandas, how do I only do a calculation for a specific subset of indices?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe X with two columns, 'report_me' and 'n'. I want to get a list (or series) that contains, for each element X where report_me is true, the sum of the n values for the previous two elements of the dataframe (regardless of their report_me values). For instance, if the data frame is:

```
X = pd.DataFrame({"report_me":[False,False,False,True,False,
                               False,True,False,False,False],
                  "n":range(10)})
```

then I want the result (3, 9).

One way to do this is:

```
sums = df['n'].shift(1) + df['n'].shift(2)
display(sums[df["report_me"]])
```

but this is slow because it computes the values of sums for *all* the indices, not just the ones that are going to be reported. One could also try filtering by report_me first:

```
reported = df[df["report_me"]]
display(reported["n"].shift(1) + reported["n"].shift(2))
```

but this gives the wrong answer because now you are getting rid of the previous values that you would be using to compute sums. Is there a way to do this that doesn't do unnecessary work?

Comment: What should happen if the first or second row (indices 0 or 1) has `True` for `"report_me"`?

Answer (score 1):

If `report_me` is sparse, you might gain some speed using a numpy solution as follows:

```
# find the index where report_me is True
idx = np.where(X.report_me.values)
# find previous two indices when report_me is True, subset the value from n, and sum
X.n.values[idx - np.arange(1,3)[:,None]].sum(axis=0)
```

<sub>You might need some extra logic to handle edge cases as pointed out in the comment</sub>

---

*Timing*:

```
%%timeit
idx = np.where(X.report_me.values)
X.n.values[idx - np.arange(1,3)[:,None]].sum(axis=0)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 23 µs per loop

%timeit X.rolling(2).n.sum().shift()[X.report_me]
#1000 loops, best of 3: 684 µs per loop

%%timeit
sums = df['n'].shift(1) + df['n'].shift(2)
sums[df["report_me"]]
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 704 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X['report_sum'] = (X.loc[X.report_me]
                    .apply(lambda x: X.iloc[[x.name-1, x.name-2]].n.sum(), 
                           axis=1))

   n  report_me  report_sum
0  0      False         NaN
1  1      False         NaN
2  2      False         NaN
3  3       True         3.0
4  4      False         NaN
5  5      False         NaN
6  6       True         9.0
7  7      False         NaN
8  8      False         NaN
9  9      False         NaN
```

If you just want the non-`NaN` values, take `.values` from the right-hand side of the assignment statement.